# How do I make a basic WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: javascript, css, editor, wysiwyg

Basically I just want bold, italic, underline. Nothing complicated.

I've read from other questions or here that I should use contenteditable. 
ie [Basic javascript wysiwyg editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644652/basic-javascript-wysiwyg-editor)

but how do I do the bold, etc from selcted text in the contenteditable box?

I need the bold, etc buttons to by CSSable, so, if I can execute javascript to do bolding, underlining, etc, that would be preferred.

Comment: I failed to build a quick demo, so here are some links to help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla, http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/ Really, this is quite Googleable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to define an element as [contentEditable](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable). Then you can use [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) to performs functions on the selected text within the contentEditable element. Documentation on this stuff is scarce... good luck :)

Of course you could use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Comment: I think I'll just make my own, since I only need 3 functions. I don't want to have to DL another plugin. (We already use Ckeditor, but we want something stupidly light weight here)

Answer (score 0):

BSALSA.com EmbeddedWB has a HTML display control and an EditDesigner that links to it giving you basic editing capability. A slight modification to the EditDesigner.pas Unit and you get near full access to MSHTML execCommand, making it a very easy to code WYSIWYG HTML editor