# Insert html code with multiple quotation marks into textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I've checked all relating questions here, but haven't find something that would resolve my issue.

I have a textarea input element is intended for email message. I need to have a button so that when you click on that it would insert a template from database (header/footer having a lot of html tags such as body, table, div etc). So it's supposed to render this html code after clicking the button so an user can see a result of template applying straight away (images, formating etc).

First of all, when I try to put it though innerHTML it doesn't change the textarea itself (it stays empty). When I try to insert it through value attribute, it inserts the code as it is (i.e. without rendering).
Secondly, I have a lot of different quotation marks in this html code and I can't know in advance where there are located and so on. How to insert a such piece of html code properly then?

Could anybody help me with this task, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic javascript wysiwyg editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644652/basic-javascript-wysiwyg-editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `contenteditable`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").innerHTML += `<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">`;
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">

</div>
<br/>
<button>Insert template</button>
```